# Useragent in PHP scraper script

Tags: php

I have a line of PHP code in a scraper script that I bought which is:

```
    $userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
```

I am guessing it means the script acts like it is Googlebot, am I correct? If this is the case, can I change it so that it's a name of my own bot like Searchbox?

Comment: The code you show is not using the `$userAgent` variable

Comment: It is basely - to lie that you're google

Comment: This is to make the people who's sites you leech happy.  Everybody is happy when google scrapes their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user agent is completely advisory, it should not have any effect on the rendered page (actually, that would be against [Google's guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66355) and result in being thrown out of the index). It should contain a URL or email webmasters can use to contact the owners of misbehaving bots.

You should not pretend to be the GoogleBot, but include your email address or homepage in the user agent.

```
$userAgent = 'scraper/1 (callum.whyte@example.com)';
```

Answer (score 0):

> If this is the case, can I change it so that it's a name of my own bot like Searchbox?

That depends on what the script does, and what kind of sites it scrapes. The Google Bot agent string is there for a reason - possibly to [trick news websites into showing paid content](http://www.techairlines.com/2011/03/18/new-york-times-paywall-loopholes/), or more innocently, to get a search engine-optimized version of the content.

If you do not need to rely on these "side effects", you can choose any user agent string you want. With bots, it is the custom to include the word "Bot", and a URL where webmasters can get more information.

Comment: A more general reason would be to make the target site serve a search-engine friendly version, which makes sense, because this script is basically the same (only for a slightly different purpose).